# Remove prefix quotes from a list of strings

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a list that includes some prefix single quotes that I really don't need.

I tried to convert them with map().

The list looks like this:

```
['{"id":"browser","top":5000}', '{"id":"amo_ef_id","top":5000}']
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[{"id":"browser","top":5000}, {"id":"amo_ef_id","top":5000}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) to safely parse the strings in the list:

```
from ast import literal_eval

list(map(literal_eval, my_list))
# [{'id': 'browser', 'top': 5000}, {'id': 'amo_ef_id', 'top': 5000}]
```